# MySQL++ Prepared Statements With Raw SQL, No Results Returned

Tags: c++, mysql++

I'm having trouble attempting to get prepared statements to work with MySQL++.  I know  that MySQL++ has no native support for prepared statements, so I thought an easy solution would just be to create prepared statements with raw SQL.

For example the following code is working correctly:

```
string* DatabaseCore::SaveNewInformation(const char * information)
{
    if (connection->connected())
    {
        Query query = connection->query("SELECT UUID();");

        string * guid = nullptr;

        if (StoreQueryResult res = query.store())
        {
            Row row = (*res.begin());
            guid = new string(row[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            UpdateErrorInformationToLastFailedQuery(query);
            return nullptr;
        }

        stringstream query_string;
        query_string << "PREPARE save_info FROM 'INSERT INTO " << ENIGMA_TABLE_NAME << " VALUES ( ?, ? )'; ";
        query_string << "SET @guid = '" << *guid << "'; ";
        query_string << "SET @info = '" << information << "'; ";
        query_string << "EXECUTE save_info USING @guid, @info; ";
        query_string << "DEALLOCATE PREPARE save_info; ";

        query.reset();
        query = connection->query(query_string.str());

        if (query.execute())
        {
            return guid;
        }
        else
        {
            delete guid;
            UpdateErrorInformationToLastFailedQuery(query);
        }
    }

    ErrorMessage = "Not connected to the database.";
    return nullptr;
}
```

That executes fine, returns no errors and successfully inserts a new row into the database as one would expect.

My issue is when I try to execute a prepared statement this way but expect it to return information.  The code in question is as follows:

```
        stringstream query_string;
        query_string << "PREPARE get_info FROM 'SELECT Information FROM " << ENIGMA_TABLE_NAME << " WHERE (Id = ?)'; ";
        query_string << "SET @guid = '" << guid << "'; ";
        query_string << "EXECUTE get_info USING @guid; ";
        query_string << "DEALLOCATE PREPARE get_info; ";

        Query query = connection->query( query_string.str() );

        std::cout << (query.more_results() ? "More Results" : "No Results") << std::endl; // Outputs "No Results"

        StoreQueryResult res = query.store();
        std::cout << res.num_rows() << std::endl; // Returns Zero
```

So while this code executes correctly with no errors it returns no results.  I know that the resulting query string is correct, for instance if I output that query string into a file and paste it into MySQL workbench it returns the information as I would expect. The problem is still present if I set the MultiStatementsOption option on the connection to be true.  I'm wondering how I can use prepared statements with MySQL++ like this and be able to retrieve information back from the executed statement.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: there's something missing in your understanding here. one of the main purposes of prepared statements (aside from performance) is to safely transmit variables to the database engine. encoding them directly in the query opens you up to data-driven security vulnerabilities and logic errors - people can inject SQL commands into your query. have another read of the documentation and look at parameter binding.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, what you're saying is that since I've used prepared statements without parameter binding I haven't actually gained any security benefits since the prepared statements as I have implemented them without parameter binding are still vulnerable to SQL injection?  If that's the case I guess my next question is whether or not MySQL++ templated queries gain me any of these security benefits.  If not I supposed I'll be forced to use the MySQL C API since I'm fairly certain that supports parameter binding and prepared statements.

Comment: The documentation is your friend there I'm afraid. We use the C api and wrap it in our own c++ wrapper classes to ensure type safety, correct resource management and exception consistency. We found the C++ API to be too unreliable and not documented well-enough so we lost faith in it.

Comment: ok I had a look at the documentation again. MySQL++ does have the concept of 'templated queries' which seem to behave similarly to parameterised queries. However the interface is non-standard (no idea why they did it that way). I have a bad feeling about this library. the non-standardness smells bad and suggests (to me) an inexperienced development team. I wouldn't be surprised to learn that it has security vulnerabilities. Personally I would avoid it.

Comment: I agree with your sentiments completely.  I think I'll also move to using MySQL C API.  Thanks for your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: no problem. I would wrap the c handles in RAII containers though - a simple shared_ptr with a custom deleter is enough.

Comment: I was planning on having a persistent connection as the program this is part of is an FCGI request handler.  Would it still make sense to use RAII in this situation ?

Comment: If you're going to use transactions, it doesn't make sense to have a persistent connection with mysql unless you have one persistent connection per thread - because transactions are tied to connections with mysql. Creating and destroying connections has very little overhead since under the covers the connections are cached anyway. Trust me - i've been through this loop and the answer is to keep it extremely simple until your users are demanding more speed. At that point, buy a second server. it's more bang for buck.

Comment: The idea was to have a single threaded program running on a docker container and spawn more containers if the load required it, gives the benefit of letting the load balancer do its thing and avoids having to multi-thread stuff.  What you said makes alot of sense though.  Thanks again for the help.